# automapper same field two conditions

Tags: automapper

I am trying to use automapper conditions with two diff conditions pointing to the same field, but the second one overrides the first, any idea?

```
         Mapper.CreateMap<src, des>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Date, o =>
        {
            o.Condition(s => s.ContainsKey("DateTaxe"));
            o.ResolveUsing<DateTaxeResolver>();
        })
        .ForMember(x => x.Date, o =>
        {
            o.Condition(s => !s.ContainsKey("DateTaxe") && s.ContainsKey("DateValue"));
            o.ResolveUsing<DateValue
```

Comment: How would you expect this to work? Why would you be trying to use two different mappings for one field?

Comment: Date could be Map to DateValue when DateTaxe is not present you may use  something like opt => opt.MapFrom (x => DateTaxe ? DateValue : DateTaxe)) the main isue is that still need the resolver mapfrom does no like custom resolvers